# What does "GDLK" mean in the videogame documentary "High Score"

Tags: terminology

[High Score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Score_(TV_series)) is a Netflix documentary about the history of video games.

Its thumbnail is just a box with GDLK written inside. I was a fool looking for several minutes for the name "High Score" and thinking it was removed from the catalog before trying to click on the first option of the menu.

This acronym isn't explained during the show (at least not in Portuguese), and I couldn't find a meaning for it that would fit the context.

[image: GDLK logo with NES controller]

Comment: Apparently GDLK is the name of the series in Brazil. In American slang, GDLK means godlike- better than any other.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I’m not entirely sure why it was even migrated here.

Comment: @LessPop - Arqade's support of defining videogame terminology has always included gaming community slang & shorthand. I'm not sure why it was migrated *from* EL&U, but it's not off-topic here.

Comment: Sure, but is this even 'video game terminology' in any meaningful sense?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=gdlk) - GDLK is an abbreviation of the phrase "God Like":

[image: Urban Dictionary Definition]

Others have suggested that the abbreviation stands for "Good Luck", but the majority seems to be standing with "God Like".